# GDB debugger does not work on WSL mdoe on VS code

Tags: c++, debugging, installation, gdb, g++

I have moved to using WSL on VS code, so I can become accustomed to linux commands. One problem that I encountered is that the debugger is not working at all, I get this error. I am also using the g++ compiler, and it is up to date. [image]

I tried to change the file name in the launch.json, but that does not work. If additional images are needed, I can provide them. I just want to solve this problem so I can focus on my uni homework and not on admin stuff :))
Also, this is my launch.json file[![enter image description here]

````
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}```
````

Comment: Install g++ in WSL, you're currently using g++ from Windows (MinGW) inside WSL (most Windows program are available in WSL).

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20170164) for why.

Comment: @Holt I installed it on ubuntu and the neccessary extensions on VS code in WSL

Comment: @AlexandruMititelu Remove `launch.json` and let VS Code recreate it then. As it is now, your `launch.json` is made for Windows.

Comment: I deleted the file and now VS code tells me the same thing: the launch program does not exist

Answer (score 0):

It finally works! Since I could not find any answer, I decided to uninstall WSL and my linux distro and do the whole proccess from scratch again.
Here are the commands for the command prompt:

Uninstall:
To uninstall app/ linux distro: winget uninstall --id <Distro.name>
To list all distros: wsl -l

Installation:
<distro.name> (in my case I simply typed Ubuntu)

Initialization:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential gdb

Then you go to VS code and in the top right of the terminal (the shortcut for the terminal is SHIFT + the button before 1) , you click the + icon to see different terminals you've got. You select WSL or the name of the distro might come up.